# How can I truncate a log file to a max number of lines from the bottom up?

Tags: bash

I have a command that logs to a file in perpetuity, appending lines to the *end* of a log file on my Ubuntu 20.04 Server machine.

I want to periodically trim off lines from the top off the file using `bash`, leaving the file `n` lines long, or untouched if the number of lines is already less than or equal to `n`.

I may have a logfile that looks like this:

```
$ cat logfile

1
2
3
```

And I want to run a command like this:

```
$ trimit -n 2 logfile
$ cat logfile

2
3
```

I've kept the last two lines, and removed any others.

Comment: So `logrotate`?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Use a tool that's specifically designed to periodically trim off lines of log files. `logrotate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail -n 2 logfile > trimmed_file
```

---

### Edit

After searching a bit I discovered the [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) utility on linux. This thread shows that even logrotate doesn't automatically use it: https://serverfault.com/questions/762558/log-backup-clashes-with-log-rotation

This is a good tutorial about this utility: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/file-locking

So basically you can do this (let source be `trim.sh`):

```
$ cat trim.sh
#!/bin/bash
tail -n 2 logfile > logfile.tmp
mv logfile.tmp logfile

$ chmod +x trim.sh

$ echo -en "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n" > logfile
$ cat logfile
1
2
3
4
5
6

$ flock --verbose logfile ./trim.sh
flock: getting lock took 0.000005 seconds
flock: executing ./trim.sh

$ cat logfile
5
6
```

Comment: And then delete logfile, and move trimmed_file in to its place?  My concern with that is losing information while that's happening.

Comment: Do you want to keep the deleted lines in another log file ?

Comment: No, it's not that, it's that what happens if in the small amount of time between duplicating the log file and emptying it, something else written to the log?

Comment: @DuncanMarshall can you see my answer ?

Comment: Yes, I can.  Perfect, thank-you.